# postgres change jsonb[] to jsonb

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I use `postgres9.4`, and there exists relation "Patients" has column "contact" with type `jsonb[]`, how to transfer type `jsonb[]` to `jsonb`?

The following is on record.

```
=>select name, contact from "Patients" where contact is not null;

name  |                                               contact                                               
--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"tom" | {"{\"name\": \"tom\", \"phone\": \"111111\", \"address\": \"shanghai\", \"relation\": \"your_relation\"}"}
```

I have tried as the followings, `contact4` is column with type `jsonb`

```
alter table "Patients" alter column contact4 type jsonb using contact4::text::jsonb;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Expected ":", but found "}".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...ress\": \"shanghai\", \"relation\": \"your_relation\"}"}
```

Comment: try `... using contact4[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the first element of jsonb array is used then the issue is simple:

```
alter table "Patients" alter column contact type jsonb using contact[1]::jsonb;
```

else you can use the following function:

```
create or replace function jsonb_array_to_jsonb(jsonb[])
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
    from unnest($1), jsonb_each(unnest)
$$;

alter table "Patients" alter column contact type jsonb using jsonb_array_to_jsonb(contact);
```

Answer (score 5):

As of 9.5 version, to preserve the data and keep the data in json as array this would work much better.

```
ALTER TABLE "Patients"  ALTER COLUMN "contact" DROP DEFAULT
ALTER TABLE "Patients"  ALTER COLUMN "contact" TYPE jsonb USING to_json(contact)
ALTER TABLE "Patients"  ALTER COLUMN "contact" SET DEFAULT '[]'
```

Comment: Good point, `to_json()` or `to_jsonb()` preserves the structure of array.