# Insert array of JSONB objects from one table as multiple rows in second table

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

We are trying to migrate data from an array column containing JSONB to a proper Postgres table.

```
{{"a":1,"b": 2, "c":"bar"},{"a": 2, "b": 3, "c":"baz"}}
```

```
 a |    b    | c
---+---------+---
 1 | 2        | "bar"
 2 | 3        | "baz"
```

As part of the process, we have made several attempts using functions like `unnest` and `array_to_json`. In the unnest case, we get several JSONB rows, but cannot figure out how to insert them into the second table. In the `array_to_json` case, we are able to cast the array to a JSON string, but the `json_to_recordset` does not seem to accept the JSON string from a common table expression.

What would be a good strategy to 'mirror' the array of JSONB items as a proper table, so that we can *run the query inside of a stored procedure, triggered on insert*?

Comment: Is the structure of the table (number, names and types of columns) known?

Comment: Yes, we have defined a second table with proper data types, and provided a schema mapping to the `json_to_recordset` call, as per the documentation.

Comment: After a bit more searching, the following looks relevant, although I don't fully understand why to use "cross join lateral" https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/2u6ah3/how_to_use_json_to_recordset_on_json_stored_in_a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest()` in a lateral join:

```
with my_data(json_column) as (
values (
    array['{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"bar"}','{"a":2,"b":3,"c":"baz"}']::jsonb[])
)
select 
    value->>'a' as a, 
    value->>'b' as b, 
    value->>'c' as c
from my_data
cross join unnest(json_column) as value

 a | b |  c  
---+---+-----
 1 | 2 | bar
 2 | 3 | baz
(2 rows)
```

You may need some casts or converts, e.g.:

```
select 
    (value->>'a')::int as a, 
    (value->>'b')::int as b, 
    (value->>'c')::text as c
from my_data
cross join unnest(json_column) as value
```

Lateral joining means that the function `unnest()` will be executed for each row from the main table. The function returns elements of the array as `value`.

Comment: Ok, I did not think anyone could use such a strange construction as `jsonb[]`. It's definitely a kind of anti-pattern. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015221/1995738 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209754/1995738

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will try your suggestions ASAP.